# change 'li' css style based on radio button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to change css style of elements on the page, based on radio button checked. I have dynamically added elements on the page, each element has 3 radio buttons, I would like when users press on the radio buttons 1,2 or 3 on each element, so the styles of each element will change ... so far I was able to change all elements styles on the page, but I like to change only particular element style..

I'm sure it is possible, but can't figure out how to do that, probably by passing the ID of each element .. ?! any help please?!

here is my code so far ...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("value") == "H") {            
            $("#somestyle li").css("border", "black");
        }
        if ($(this).attr("value") == "M") {
            $("#somestyle li").css("border", "blue");
        }
        if ($(this).attr("value") == "L") {
            $("#somestyle li").css("border", "yellow");
        }
    });
});
```

this code changing all `li` elements style, but not the one I've clicked. How to change ONLY one element style?! Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: need to see your html

Comment: "this code changing all 'li' elements style, but not the one I've clicked". The event callback is bound to the "click" event on `input[type="radio"]` elements, not `li` elements. You don't click the `li`, you click the radio buttons. If you want to change the style of only one element, then just select that element in `$("...").css` function calls. Also, please fix your code.

Comment: How radio and li and related to each other?

Comment: The html created dynamically from database package. will try to post it in here the main points ... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `closest` (or `parent`) method to get only corresponding `li` element. So it will be:

```
if (this.value == "H") {            
    $(this).closest("li").css("border", "black");
}
```

and so on for other sizes.

However you can also improve your code significantly by using CSS classes instead of inline styles. So the code will become:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
    $(this).closest("li").addClass(this.value);
});
```

and provide a classes like this:

```
li.H {
    border-color: black;
}
```

The benefit is obvious: it's much simpler to style li elements with backgrounds, colors, etc.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2mu0tdzo/

Comment: This answer is brittle. What if there is a change in the HTML (although not provided in the question, yet) and the closest LI is not the one whose style needed to be changed? In the absence of the HTML I would suggest using an ID to pick the appropriate LI element

Comment: @dade Well in case of OP, it's LI elements. In general in this specific case it's hard to provide generic solution that would work for any possible markup, even if something like `.closest('.size-options')` is used. But sine in our case based on `code changing all li elements style, but not the one I've clicked` - I assume that radio button are inside list items.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, you've just saved me a lot of time and headache !!!! works as it should work !!! THANKS!